# PHP check if contents are available

Tags: php, http, onavailable

I am using random.org in my php script to generate random numbers like that:

```
    function getToken($length){
        $r = explode('
',file_get_contents('http://www.random.org/integers/?num='.$length.'&min=0&max=9&col=1&base=10&format=plain'));
        $string = '';
        foreach ( $r as $char ) $string.=$char;
        return $string;
    }
```

but my university net denies such queries, so whenewer i test my project using university wifi, i dont get random numbers to be generated, and that means trouble.

So, i before using this function, it needs to be chect if i can query random.org or not like that:

```
    if( site is accessible ) return getToken();
    else return false;
```

what would be the best way to check accesability?

Myself i tried:

```
    file_get_contents();
```

but it sends warnings,whenewer it fails,

```
    dns_get_record();
```

but i dont know if i can trust that, if it checks only dns name. 
Please help!

P.S. a pinging technique might proove usefull...

Comment: Why don't you generate the random numbers in your script yourself? I mean is there a specific reason why you are using `random.org`?

Comment: because it generates real random numbers

Comment: so does `mt_rand()`: http://php.net/mt_rand

Comment: Seriously, there's an api for random numbers ?

Comment: actually, its pseudo-random. But you got the point, maybe that would go for the best. Anyway i still wanna know how to check availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run `file_get_contents` with `@` to supress errors and simply return when it doesn't give you a random number, resulting in something like:

```
function getToken($length){
    $number = @file_get_contents('http://www.random.org/integers/?num='.$length.'&min=0&max=9&col=1&base=10&format=plain');
    if($number === false) return null;
    $r = explode('',$number);
    $string = '';
    foreach ( $r as $char ) $string.=$char;
    return $string;
}
```

That being said, I seriously doubt if you really need to use random.org to generate random numbers. PHP's own pseudo-random generator functions include `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` that is said to generate "cryptographically strong" pseudorandom numbers:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Comment: i tried open_ssl, but dramaticly it's forbidden in the host i'm using

Comment: I didn't knew that @ thing, thats a usefull post. Not only you tought me how to solve the problem, but tought me something valuable. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, and as i said, i cant use open ssl, but instead i will collect generated random entries and generate only unique number combinations.

Comment: Glad you liked it. And it's ok - just go with what you can and need to use!